# bundle console fails w/ uninitialized constant Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have create a new Rails engine using the `rails plugin new Foobar --full --mountable` command. When running `bundle console` I get `uninitialized constant Rails` Why is this?

```
Resolving dependencies...
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/Users/kyledecot/Desktop/Foobar/lib/foobar/engine.rb:2:in `<module:Foobar>': uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)
    from /Users/kyledecot/Desktop/Foobar/lib/foobar/engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kyledecot/Desktop/Foobar/lib/foobar.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/kyledecot/Desktop/Foobar/lib/foobar.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:664:in `console'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:438:in `start'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/bin/bundle:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/bin/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@foobar/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@foobar/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: did you bundle install?

Comment: @Derek Yes. When running the command to create the plugin/engine a bundle install is automatically done.

Comment: I am getting this error message also.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `require 'rails'` in `Foobar/lib/foobar/engine.rb` file worked for me. I got my answer from [here](https://github.com/pat/combustion/issues/27).